# how to unset particular session in every controller except one controller

Tags: session, laravel

Laravel Problem: I want to unset particular session on every controller except one(specific) controller.

I am thinking of helper class. But if is there better way (like middle ware).

If is anyone have idea, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Middleware is a good idea, you can use easily with your routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'clearSession'], function () {
    // .. your controllers
});

// A controller where not clear
Route::controller('mycontroller', 'MyController');
```

But you can also add to your controllers constructor, and you don't have to mess with current routes, route groups.